# "ionic cordova platform add ios" returns ENOENT error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

When I run the command `ionic cordova platform add ios` inside my ionic project the terminal shows the following error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/angelinatsuboi/Desktop/Deals2Meals/ios/package.json'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/Users/angelinatsuboi/Desktop/Deals2Meals/ios/package.json'
}
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this error by deleting the ios directory underneath the root project directory and then running

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
```